# Python typing.overload and subclass implementation removes Pycharm code completion

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9

```
from typing import overload 

class Foo:
    @overload
    def a(self, value: int):
       ...
    @overload
    def a(self, value: str):
       ...
    def a(self, value):
        print(value)
```

This correctly shows the overloaded signature on the parent class `Foo`:

[image]

If we subclass `Foo` and do not override the implementation function, the overloaded type hints are visible as expected:

```
class Bar(Foo):
    pass
```

The type hints are inherited and show up as expected:

[image]

However, if we subclass `Foo` and override the implementation function, the overloaded type hints are lost:

```
class Bar(Foo):
    def a(self, value):
        print(value)
```

[image]

---

Is there any way to preserve the overloaded type hints in a subclass that overrides the implementing method, short of duplicating the overloaded type hints in the subclass?

Comment: As a non-PyCharm user, I'm curious: does `Bar().a()` show both type hints if you *don't* override `Foo.a`?

Comment: @chepner Yes it does. Does your IDE? I've edited the OP to include this.

Comment: "However, if we subclass Foo and override the implementation function, the overloaded type hints are lost:" I suspect the following is happening: basically, because you are defining a function without *any* annotations, static type checkers will either *reject this altogether in strict mode* or just use `typing.Any` for everything. ALthough, potentially some of these might infer to see whether it can infer the same signature, but apparently, PyCharm does not

Comment: Anyway, I can confirm that `mypy` also infers `"def (self: test.Bar, value: Any) -> Any` for `Bar.a` and `pyright` as well loses the information and infers "Unown" for the argument type. Note, the methods in your `Foo` class should have `self`, was that just a mistaken omission when you were creating your question?

Comment: Anway, I'd just bight the bullet here and annotate both. If you used a third-party static type checker, you would at least be warned if you changed one without the other and break it

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga sorry, it was a mistaken omission. Fixed now. The problem with annotating both is that I am creating a framework and want consumers to subclass my class and override the method. So my consumers might not even know about the annotations and will lose these type hints during code completion.

Comment: I don't use an IDE, just `vim`.